# What does a ELF64 File look like?

Tags: linux, assembly, compiler-construction, 64-bit, elf

Ok.

So i have been messing around with Assembly, and i was wondering: just HOW does a linkes ELF64 File look like, and can i directly write a linked file in plain-text? (like create a file e.G "main", write the hex-values of the system-calls, and then run it without linking or assembling.)

I have tried `objdump -x main` but i don't think, this is the entire ELF-File, because there is too less information, as i think.

Here the output:

```
main:     Dateiformat elf64-x86-64

Inhalt von Abschnitt .text:
 4000b0 b8040000 00bb0100 0000b9d0 006000ba  .............`..
 4000c0 0c000000 cd80b801 000000cd 80        .............   
Inhalt von Abschnitt .data:
 6000d0 48454c4c 4f2c2057 4f524c44           HELLO, WORLD
```

my Assembler Code:

```
section .data
        msg: db "HELLO, WORLD"
        len: equ $-msg

section .text


        ;write
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, msg
        mov edx, len
        int 80h;

        ;quit
        mov eax, 1
        int 80h;
```

EDIT: My Compiler is finished now, I just stuck with assembler and let NASM/ld do the job

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation on how ELF is structured?

Comment: do you mean `man elf`

Comment: That's a good source to get started.

Comment: ok. now: can i just write out the thing in plain-text or do i have to write it e.G. with an HEX-Editor?

Comment: ELF is a binary file format. There is no plain-text format. You can use the `libelf` to parse an ELF file, alternatively you can use a hexeditor.

Comment: and how can i write the hex without an hex editor, i mean, how can i do this with Lazarus Pascal (my Programming Language, in which i build the compiler)

Comment: Use the libelf or read the documentation and build your own tools. That said, your compiler should output assembly, not elf binaries. Making an object file out of the assembly is the assembler's job, making the binary out of the object files is the linker's job. Neither things should be done by your compiler.

Comment: That said, look at the tinycc project for inspiration on how to generate ELF files in an unsophisticated manner.

Comment: Ok. Got it.  But how does a normal compiler do it?  Do they have their own linker,  or do they run ths Linux -  assembler?

Comment: Most compilers use the system assembler and linker. That's what the compiler is supposed to do and that's they easiest way to program a compiler.

Comment: ok. Thank you. That was m yoriginal convept, but i wanted to do it more difficult. Maybe, i was overestimating myself :)

Comment: Don't edit your question to say it's solved.  SO already tracks whether there's an accepted answer or not.

Comment: ok. Thank you for the Information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the entire structure of your executable try:

```
objdump -D some_exe
```

and if you want to see your file in hex format do:

```
xxd some_exe
```

or

```
hexdump some_exe
```

> can i directly write a linked file in plain-text?

Well... Theoretically you can if you know exactly the instructions of the executable and you write them in binary to a plaintext file.

For example, for any given executable **exe_file** you can do this:

```
touch temp_file plaintext_file
xxd -p exe_file > temp_file
xxd -p -r temp_file > plaintext_file
chmod u+x plaintext_file
```

The **plaintext_file** will be an executable exactly the same as your **exe_file**. If between steps 2 and 3 you modify the **temp_file** you are directly modifying the executable by hand, although it is not very likely to change something "specific", unless you have very deep understanding of elf64 format (which I don't and I'm not sure what can be achieved with this).

Note: I know step 1 is redundant, I used it for demonstrating that you are starting with 2 simple plaintext files.

Comment: ok. But now the tricky part: i wanted to build a compiler wich just writes out a plaintext, saves it and then chmods it. is this possible, or am i a little too ambitoned?

Comment: and other question: why is there so much blank space?

Comment: i mean why is there so much blank space, when i run xxd?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understood what kind of compiler you want to write? For the other question I believe you want to read the format specifics here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: i already looked to wikipedia, but i don't see for example: how to initiate a system-call in elf64. For the Compiler: i want to write a compiler, which compiles code into a exe. Tho other possibility is, i just put everything as assembler-file and assemble and link it, but that's no challenge and by extension no fun.

Comment: This might help also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438057/interesting-binary-dump-of-executable-file Read the first answer

Comment: Writing a compiler is a very different task than just understanding the elf format. I'm not saying it's not possible but you'll haveto study different things. Just google on how to write a simple compiler or something like that, there are plenty of guides out there.

Comment: if you mean the parsing algorythm: i already have programmed an Interpreter, and i wanted to add a 'Compiler' -Function to it.

Comment: `how to initiate a system-call in elf64`: totally unrelated to object-file format.  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/1164/introduction-to-x86/19078/x86-linux-hello-world-example for making syscalls.  Of course, normal C compilers on Linux don't ever emit direct system calls, and just call the library wrapper functions.  Emitting a library function call (to a dynamically linked library) does of course depend on the object file format.